# malloc: *** error for object 0x1029249b0: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, c++11

I'm trying to compile a program which contains -std=c++0x on a mac OS X 10.6.8 with xcode 3.2.6. I upgraded my g++ compiler to g++-4.7 with homebrew. In my makefile I changed the lines from:

```
CXX          = g++
CXXFLAGS     = -std=c++0x
LD           = g++
LDFLAGS      = -L.
```

to:

```
CXX          = g++-4.7
CXXFLAGS     = -std=c++0x
LD           = g++-4.7
LDFLAGS      = -L.
```

however, this line wasn't working:

```
$(CC) -c -Icore/include/ -Ianalysis/include -Ieventbuilders/include -Isimdut/include -Istyle/include $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

so I changed it to:

```
$(CXX) -c -Icore/include/ -Ianalysis/include -Ieventbuilders/include -Isimdut/include -Istyle/include $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

everything now compiles, but when I run my file I get the following error:

```
tbmon(25203) malloc: *** error for object 0x1029249b0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

Could someone please advise me what I've done wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's almost impossible to say if this is a bug in the compiler (probably not) or a bug in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a bug in the program where it calls [`free()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) on a pointer that wasn't obtained with `malloc()`. Or some other memory-related bug in the code that triggers this behavior.

Make files you have provided are not related to this problem. You have to fix the program code.

Comment: Since it's C++, it could also be a call to `delete`, which in turn uses `free` to do the memory freeing.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Could be. The point is that program code is buggy, and makefiles are not likely to fix it... :-|

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the compiler from, presumably, gcc to g++ shouldn't cause `free(3)` to fail. Could you please post a minimal example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: It could easily do so if the program's behavior is undefined. The program was buggy already, but didn't show this particular symptom.